# Killing specific PHP process

Tags: php, linux

How do you kill a PHP process running a specific script?.

I have several cronjobs that run different php scripts every hour. So let's say I have cron1.php, cron2.php and cron3.php. Whenever I run cron2.php, I want to kill all running instances of PHP executing THAT one script (and not cron1.php or cron3.php). I could do "killall php" but that will stop all of them.

Comment: please note that I've considered setting the php execution time to match the cron timing, but that doesn't really serve my purpose

Comment: What is your script doing that makes this necessary in the first place? Killing the script sounds like the wrong way to do it (and I'm not aware of a way to list what PHP processes run what file, anyway)

Comment: Passing `-j`, for example, to `ps` provides the command name in the output (i.e. `php foo.php`). Check the man pages; you should find an even more appropriate argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kill `pgrep -f cron2.php`
```

Thanks to Waleed Khan for showing the right path